# Update the listbox items for the selected elements in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, listbox

if i already added and few stations are selected for the same added Element like below
Roads– ATL, MSP, MAA
Now again selected  Roads– BOM, CFX, ATL. Then append the stations  to the existing (I mean first we have to check if the Element already exists and the stations added for the second time does not exists). So we found that Roads is already there and ATL is already there. Then our resultant will be like below

Comment: I'm afraid you forgot to add your example.